# How do I get Facebook Like button to show the link and not just say "Jim likes a link" on a Wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

In the text view of a WordPress post, I pasted this code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?   href=https://thebarneyreview.com&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When I click on the Share button, it works fine. It posts a link and preview of website you are sharing.

When I click the Like button, it just shows up in my Facebook activity log as "Jim likes a link" instead of "Jim likes thebarneyreview.com" or something that shows what I'm liking. And it doesn't show up in anybody's newsfeed. Is there something I need to change in the code or am I wrong about how the Like button should work?

Answer (score 0):

On scraping your url using the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object), I can see that the Open Graph meta tags are missing from your page. It seems like you need to add these tags to alter how your story renders. e.g. if you set the `og:type` to `article`, the story will render as '`Foobar likes an article on ...`'. You can look at the docs about the Open Graph meta tags [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects).